# What is the order of return value for field_info_instances?

Tags: 7, entities

I've used `field_info_instances` function to retrieve all fields info under a content type.

`field_info_instances('$entity_type','$bundle_name')`.

As from [API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7) page,

1. If `$entity_type` is not set, return all instances keyed by entity
   type and bundle name.
2. If `$entity_type` is set, return all instances for that entity type,
   keyed by bundle name.
3. If `$entity_type` and `$bundle_name` are set, return all instances for
   that bundle.

I didn't get the third point here. what is the default order for return output by `file_info_instances` when `$entity_type` and `$bundle_name` given.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query run by [`field_read_instances()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_read_instances/7):

```
$query = db_select('field_config_instance', 'fci', array('fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$query->join('field_config', 'fc', 'fc.id = fci.field_id');
$query->fields('fci');

// Turn the conditions into a query.
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
  $query->condition('fci.' . $key, $value);
}
if (!$include_inactive) {
  $query->condition('fc.active', 1)->condition('fc.storage_active', 1);
}
if (!$include_deleted) {
  $query->condition('fc.deleted', 0);
  $query->condition('fci.deleted', 0);
}

$instances = array();
$results = $query->execute();
```

So it's safe to say there's no default order for field instances; they'll be in whatever order they went into the database, or perhaps different depending on your DBMS and settings.